# Accesing LDT register in x64 application c++

Tags: c++, virtual-machine

im trying to detect VM using LDT register but i've encoutered a problem. In x64 there are no inline asm so i have to use intrinsics, but there aren't any intrinsic for ldt. In x86 it looks like this:

```
UCHAR ldtr[5] = "\xef\xbe\xad\xde";
_asm sldt ldtr
unsigned long ldt = *((unsigned long *)&ldtr[0]);
```

Is there any possible workaround to implement it in x64 ?

Compiler: from visual studio

Version: 1915

Comment: It would help if you told us your compiler and version of it, as both inline assembly and intrinsics is very compiler-dependent.

Comment: im using visual studio and compiler provided with that (checked with 
    #if _MSC_VER >=1915 ) and the version is 1915

Comment: Are you running in protected mode? If so are you expecting to be running this code in kernel mode or user mode?

Comment: Yes im running it in protected mode, but i can adjust to kernel or user mode, any possible solution for x64 build will satisfy me, but preferably in user mode

Comment: When you say detect VM? Do you mean detecting if you're in a VM, or if Virtual Memory is being used? In long mode AFAIK Virtual Memory is a requirement. Moreover most modern OS' avoid using the LDT as it can create security risks it seems. I'm trying to understand what the overall goal is. Because at least on windows 10 Anniversary update assuming you can read the LDTR it should always be zero (the kernel will crash the system if it's not apparently).

Comment: I mean being in virtual machine. As far as i know using the code that i attached to my question, will return value: " dead0000" on physical machine (tested on win7 tomorrow i can test it on win10) on the other hand nothing has changed on VM: "deadbeaf" (tested on win10), but my professor requested this app to be written in x64 (project for studies), so im trying to find solution for this problem.